# Overwrite function and call other function in extended class

Tags: java, inheritance, lego-mindstorms

My motors of my `NXT2 2.0` is backwards and now everytime I run the command `forward()` it rolls backwards instead. I am using the `DifferentialPilot` to move my robot, and therefore want to overwrite several functions in the `DifferentialPilot` class.

I inherited from that class and overwrote all constructors with my custom ones.
Then I overwrote `forward()` which should now call `backward()`, and vice versa.

However, Now I'm getting exceptions, and I can't really tell why.

Here is the overwritten class:

```
package lejos.robotics.navigation;
import lejos.robotics.RegulatedMotor;

public class CustomDifferentialPilot extends DifferentialPilot {

    public CustomDifferentialPilot(final double wheelDiameter, final double trackWidth, final RegulatedMotor leftMotor,
            final RegulatedMotor rightMotor) {
        super(wheelDiameter, trackWidth, leftMotor, rightMotor);

    }

    public CustomDifferentialPilot(final double wheelDiameter, final double trackWidth, final RegulatedMotor leftMotor,
            final RegulatedMotor rightMotor, final boolean reverse) {
        super(wheelDiameter, trackWidth, leftMotor, rightMotor, reverse);
    }

    public CustomDifferentialPilot(double leftWheelDiameter, double rightWheelDiameter, double trackWidth,
            RegulatedMotor leftMotor, RegulatedMotor rightMotor, boolean reverse) {
        super(leftWheelDiameter, rightWheelDiameter, trackWidth, leftMotor, rightMotor, reverse);
    }

    public void forward() {
        backward();
    }

    public void backward() {
        forward();
    }

}
```

And my example code for the robot:

```
import lejos.robotics.navigation.CustomDifferentialPilot;


public class DriveTest {

    private static CustomDifferentialPilot diffPilot;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        diffPilot = new CustomDifferentialPilot(10, 20, Motor.A, Motor.B);
        diffPilot.forward();
    }

}
```

Is calling a function from the superclass, in the subclass within an overwritten method not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to pass `super()` to the overridden methods.

```
public void forward() {
    super.backward();
}

public void backward() {
    super.forward();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method does not actually create an instance of `diffPilot`.  You should be getting a NullPointerException at `diffPilot.forward();`.

You should be doing

```
diffPilot = new CustomDifferentialPilot(...);
```

in your main method before calling `.forward()`;

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely one stupid mistake. I'm still getting exceptions though.

Comment: Unless you post the complete stacktrace it's going to be really hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: I know. That's why it is really hard for me to debug as well, because I don't see the whole stacktrace myself, because it is only displayed on the LCD of the NXT. So the actual overwriting should work that way?